# Implementing AMR encoder

Tags: algorithm, audio, encoding, pcm, amr

I have 8k 16bit PCM and I want to implement algorithm for converting it to AMR. How should I proceed?
I need some kind of guide or tutorial explaining how to encode PCM to AMR.
Note: For now I only need to be able to encode PCM to AMR without decoding mechanisms.

Comment: Tried to goole around? (e.g. [AMR codecs](http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/amr))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all I needed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec in the links section.